# What happens if a atom which can absorb a photon is placed behind a double slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, double-slit-experiment

Suppose there's an atom with an excited electron. So it will emit a photon at a definite frequency when the electron comes back from the excited state, which will spread like a spherical wave.

Now if there is a similar atom nearby, the atom's electron will absorb the photon and go to an excited state.

But if instead of the atom there is a double slit, the photon will continue spreading like a wave and so make an interference pattern.

But if a double slit and also a similar atom is placed at an equal distance from the source, then what will happen?

I'm pretty new to quantum physics and this question just popped into my head after learning about the wave particle duality. I think I'm mistaken somewhere.

Comment: -1 for a lousy subject line. Perhaps some concepts that might help:, The electron is not excited, the atom is.  Then think of the "photon" as an excitation of the EM field.  (The photon as a particle can be a useful metaphor, but not in this case.) Now you can think about the two sub-systems, atom and field, interacting and  the excitation passing from one to the other.

Comment: @garyp Isn’t the electron in an excited state?

Comment: The atom is in an excited state.  The electron is just an electron.  This is not mere semantics.  e.g.:  for  a book $x$ meters above the floor potential energy is undefined.  For the Earth-book system, potential energy is defined.

Comment: Just to note, a double slit is also made of atoms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work like this. Almost everything about your description of what might happen is oversimplified to the point where it's wrong.

> So it will emit a photon at a definite frequency when the electron comes back from the excited state, which will spread like a spherical wave.

1. Spectral lines have non-zero width, cf. e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Line_broadening_and_shift). There is no reason to expect that the "emitted" state is that of a single photon with definite frequency. Instead it is a superposition of photon states with frequencies with a probability density for the frequencies that of the corresponding spectral line.
2. The emitted state does not "spread as a spherical wave" on its own. Until you have detected some emitted photon somewhere or measured the momentum or energy of the atom, the system "atom + surroundings" is in a superposition of "atom is still excited" and "atom is not excited + photon has been emitted". This situation is not so simple that you can treat the atom as being in a definite state and the photon spreading, the atom and the potentially emitted photon state are entangled. Momentum is conserved, and when you detect either the photon or the atom with a particular momentum, entanglement is destroyed and the other necessarily is in a state with the corresponding "recoil momentum". This isn't really relevant to the rest of this situation, but it might be good to keep in mind.
3. Photons, as relativistic spin 1 particles, do not have proper position operators like other particles do, and hence do not have ordinary wavefunctions for a probability of being localized at a point. The most you can say without treading on controversial ground is that photons have probabilities to cross specific (detector) surfaces at specific points.

> Now if there is a similar atom nearby, the atom's electron will absorb the photon and go to an excited state.

No, there is a probability that it will do so. Even in the simplified picture where there is a spherical wavefunction spreading, this would only be a probability. When you put more atoms/double slits/whatever there, then the probability that the photon interacts with at least one of them will rise, but you don't have any guarantees.

Until you do some measurement to figure out what happens, the entire system will, once again, be in a superposition of states like "photon was absorbed by another atom" + "photon was diffracted by the double slit". When you do a measurement, there's some probability you'll see results consistent with one of these histores, and some probability you'll see results corresponding to the other.

Comment: So nothing can be said before measurement? Then why are all these probabilities needed? Why do we need to calculate all these probabilities, if we can't say anything for sure from these probabilities?

Comment: @Theoretical I don't understand what you're saying - the very nature of probabilities is that we can't say "anything for sure". But would you claim that just because you can't know for sure that you won't win the lottery, knowing the chances that you might win it is useless? In the absence of certainty, a reliable probability is the next best thing. Please also note that comments are not for follow-up questions, if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to quantum physics too, but I think I can give you some insight from the way I personally understand this, but not a complete, definite answer.

The scenario you described is very similar to the scenario of a half-silvered mirror that splits a beam of light into 2 (orthogonal) light beams with lower intensity.

If we consider that the incident beam of light is monochromatic, then all the photons in that beam will have the same frequency, energy, you name it : they're all identical photons.

The conundrum lives in the fact that identical photons seem to be "treated" differently by the half-silvered mirror that splits the beam into two. Even Einstein rejected this idea that the photons seem to be divided "by chance" rather than a well-defined difference in some physical property (which isn't quite obvious in the case of identical photons).

The idea that the photons seem to split haphazardly causes quantum mechanics to be a non-deterministic science, that is: well defined results can't be perfectly postulated for some initial conditions.

The point is, **from my personal understanding of the matter**, you can't determine the fate of **one** photon in an experiment.. But you (theoretically and experimentally) **can** determine the "fraction" or "probability" of the total photons that will undergo a certain fate, because of the non-deterministic nature of quantum physics.

Although Einstein is the one who put forward the idea of photons, he knew that his idea will cause problems like this one here.

Maybe someone else will provide a definite answer for your question, but reflecting back on the light-splitting example, perhaps there isn't one!

Best of luck learning QM.